# Creating large matrices in R in reasonable time

Tags: r, performance

I am working on a movie recommender predicts a user's movie rating for an unseen movie. Most of the work is done and I have created a 7000x3000 matrix *userRatingsNew* containing 7000 users and their ratings for 3000 movies, replacing all the missing values with the predicted rating.

I was provided two other files, *mapping* and *test*, and used read.csv() to load them into matrices of the following format.

*mapping* is a 8,400,000x3 matrix that contains *id, user, movie*, where *id* is basically the transaction id associated with a user's rating of movie x.

*test* is a 8,400,000x2 matrix that contains *id, rating*, where rating is the user's rating for that movie associated with *id*. The values in the *rating* column are empty and I need to fill those in using the predicted values that I have already calculated.

Here is my code

```
writeResult <- function(userRatingsNew, mapping, test, writeToFile = FALSE){
start <- Sys.time()

result <- test
entries <- nrow(test)
for (i in 1:entries){
    result[i,2] <- userRatingsNew[mapping[i,2], mapping[i,3]]
}
if (writeToFile)
    write.csv(result, "result.csv", row.names=FALSE)

print(Sys.time()-start)
return(result)
```

}

My problem is that for i=1:100, it takes ~7 seconds. So in order to process all 8.4 million entries, it'd take ~163 hours. I tried using doMC() and implemented parallel processing, but I ran into the problem where my computer ran out of memory. What exactly can I do to speed this process up?

Comment: Have you tried this *instead of the loop*: `result[,2] <- userRatingsNew[mapping[,2:3]]`??

Comment: What is your platform and specs?

Comment: W7 64-bit, 3.20GHz quad core, and 8GB DDR2 RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index a matrix with another matrix, as in:

```
M <- matrix(1:25,nc=5,nr=5)
M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
# [2,]    2    7   12   17   22
# [3,]    3    8   13   18   23
# [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
# [5,]    5   10   15   20   25

m <- cbind(1:5,5:1)
m
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    5
# [2,]    2    4
# [3,]    3    3
# [4,]    4    2
# [5,]    5    1
M[m]
# [1] 21 17 13  9  5
```

So try

```
result[,2] <- userRatingsNew[mapping[,2:3]]
```

You should not need a loop.

Comment: That fixed everything for me. At first, it didn't work, but that was due to error on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A thought:

Instead of the 3000-sized dimension attached directly to the 7000-sized dimension, for each user you can attach an array which specifies the movie id/number/place in array, and their rating, in a series of 2d datapoints. Presumably most users will not rate all 3000 films. Let's say they rate 20 movies on average, and in each of 20 cases now it calls the array of movie names by correctly referring to the location in the array, then now you only need (7000) x (20x2+20) things going on, where 20x2 refers to the 20 ratings plus the reference to the film, and the other 20 is the fact of retrieving the film name. You can compile all reports first using array location and attach the name referring to an array of film names.

Comment: The 7000x3000 matrix is filled. All of the missing values for unrated movies were replaced with a predicted rating, so I can't decrease the dimension.

Comment: If it's already in matrix form, then you can mix and match any and all dimensions in any which way, so there is no need to concern yourself with whether the matrix is already "filled". Let's say you have an Excel sheet, 7000x3000, and you've decided to store the data like that for interim uses. You build 7000 arrays, each of which contains the locator of each datapoint which contains the entry. That's supposed to be the key benefit of working with a matrix/array structure, is that in can be manipulated in any way if the data is structured right in the first place.